# How to mouse proof an old slanted roof?

Tags: roof

I'm working on an old house insulating the roof. I used mesh wire filled with construction foam to seal holes and cracks to prevent mice from entering.

Most of the slanted parts of the roof are above the attic/storage rooms so it's not the end of the world if some mice can "visit". However one part which gives me headaches is a guest room under the slanted roof.

Since mice can also enter through the tiles of the roof, I fear that they could destroy the underlayment and enter the insulation layer.

What is the best way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Mice will chew through foam, so that's not going to do much for you. They'll also squeeze through all but the tiniest wire mesh (thing window screen material to be safe).

Comment: I now use 1.6cm diameter mesh but multiple layers displaced to make it harder for them to enter.

Comment: 16mm is roughly 3/4". A small mouse will get right through that. A large one might squeeze through. Offsetting 2 layers by 50% (so you have 8mm gaps) is good, but they may get industrious and push until the mesh stretches a bit, then squeeze through. You'd be amazed at what they'll do for a meal...

Comment: @FreeMan I'm using 3-4 layers and displacing them as good as possible. Then fill them up with foam. Got the idea from Shawn Woods https://youtu.be/FJ5aoSNS2ow

Comment: 3mm or 1/8" welded mesh is generally effective for mice. 6mm or 1/4 inch (or larger) is generally not.