# Alternatives to 3mm welded mesh for mice protection?

Tags: pest-control

One room of my house is below a slanted roof. The tiles on the roof are quite old, so mice can probably enter through the tiles. I want to use a classic design for insulation. (From top to bottom). Underlay, Insulation, Moisture barrier. I have read that mice can bite through the underlay to get into the insulation layer, thus I want to protect the underlay with welded mesh wire, so the mesh wire will be installed as the outermost layer under the tiles. I can't use copper wool, since I have to cover an extensive area of about 10-15m2.

In a comment to this [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/275012/how-to-mouse-proof-an-old-slanted-roof) the User "Ecnerwal" suggested to use 3mm mesh wire.

I have done an extensive search for welded 3mm mesh. However welded mesh of this mesh size is very hard to get. The smallest I could find so far is 3.5mm but the price is very high, about 50 Euro per m2.

I'm also starting to question the 3mm number. I found [this](https://www.icup.org.uk/media/b3gdr1t2/icup1198.pdf) research paper stating

> While extremely good guides, they do contain an important
> error – they confuse the statement that mice can squeeze under a ¼ inch (approximately 6 mm) gap with
> a later figure that shows a round hole of ¼ inch diameter, clearly too small for even a newly-weaned
> mouse to get through. Howeve,r facts such as this can become accepted wisdom in the pest control
> industry, especially in the absence of recent basic behavioural research on proofing techniques.

This [guide](https://extensionpublications.unl.edu/assets/html/g1530/build/g1530.htm) by the University of Nebraska lists 6mm as being effective against mice.

> Rats only need slightly more than a ½-inch gap to enter; mice only need slightly more than a ¼-inch gap

Texas A&M University also has a [guide](https://schoolipm.tamu.edu/forms/pest-management-plans/ipm-action-plan-for-rodents/) stating the 1/4" as being effective against mice.

> Open access points as small as 1/4 inch in diameter for mice 1/2 inch for rats act like beacons, attracting rodents with warm air and food smells.
>
> Seal any openings greater than 1/4 inch in diameter in foundations, walls, fascia, and roofs. Screen vents and install door sweeps to prevent access. If rats are entering through floor drains, seal these with hardware cloth with mesh smaller than 1/2 inch.

The [University of Massachusetts](https://ag.umass.edu/greenhouse-floriculture/fact-sheets/preventing-rodent-damage-in-greenhouses) gives a similar number.

> Some rodents such as mice can get in through openings as small as ¼ inch.

The [University of Utah](https://extension.usu.edu/news_sections/gardening/vole-damage) gives a similar number

> The mesh should be 1/4 inch or less in size

Comment: No, since for large areas copper mesh is not suitable. I need to protect my underlay since mice can also enter through the tiles. Also the comments do not specify which mesh size to use

Comment: Do you need the ventilation/passage of stuff that a mesh provides?  If not then a solid piece of metal will provide mice/rat blockage and you do not need to worry about size or welded or not.  Most of those links are for covering holes in walls/floors, not for floors/walls without holes, which your underlay/tiles should not have or you have made a goof.

Comment: You need to add that info to the question, @CuriousIndeed. Because buried down here in the comments it's not likely to get read by everyone. While you're editing that in, you may want to indicate (in the question) why the copper mesh won't work for you.

Comment: I think 6mm is too wide.

Comment: @FreeMan Tried to clarify the question.

Comment: @RohitGupta Not according to all the sources I found from universities

Comment: @CuriousIndeed - my experience differs.  Maybe their mice are fatter.  It would be silly to put in 6mm mesh and then find out that it doesn't work.  `Open access points as small as 1/4 inch in diameter for mice 1/2 inch for rats act like beacons, attracting rodents with warm air and food smells.` doesn't say what you are interpreting it to be.  They act like beacons, because the holes are large.  It doesn't say then cant enter through narrower holes.

Comment: @RohitGupta Added another passage from the same document to clarify. Did you ever use 1/4 inch rustfree, WELDED mesh and it did not work? Did you check why it did not work?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your desired application but if you really want a 3mm mesh you could get perforated sheet metal.

To prevent rodents entering the roof: There are matching products widely available. Ask for "metal eave combs" at your local building supply.

Comment: Surely mice cannot get through 1/4 inch mesh "hardware cloth". This would be square openings 6.35 mm on each side, 9 mm diagonal.

Comment: @JimStewart yes, without doubt. I didn't read his citations, so I just went the "he wants it - he gets it" route.